# Travis CI: config not read

Tags: java, maven, travis-ci

I'm building a Maven project with Travis CI. At some step in the build, the GPG plugin is being called. No passphrase is provided, so it fails.

I've tried to override the build lifecycle phases to prevent the GPG plugin from being activated. However, my custom steps don't seem to be executed.

The `.travis.yml` file in question is [here](https://github.com/endreman0/java-json/blob/master/.travis.yml). However, viewing the [build log](https://travis-ci.org/endreman0/java-json/builds/71335837) on Travis, I still see the default build commands being called. Nowhere in the log is any of my custom build lifecycle called.

Why is Travis not reading the repository's `.travis.yml` file? I've used the web linter, and it checks out there. I've run all of the commands in the build file locally, and they all execute correctly. I can't see anything wrong with my Travis configuration/setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file `.travis.yml` is being successfully read, but the execution is breaking in [this command](https://github.com/endreman0/java-json/blob/master/.travis.yml#L9):

```
mvn install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -Dsource.skip=true -Dgpg.skip=true -B
```

Reading the log... the problem seems to be with the maven-gpg-plugin. Check line 1498 of the [log you post](https://travis-ci.org/endreman0/java-json/builds/71335837).

The error: gpg secret key is not avaiable. [Possible solution](http://www.michaelpollmeier.com/maven-skip-pgp-sign-process/).

Since that command is breaking the execution, the build stops prematurely.

Comment: The `-Dgpg.skip=true` option should disable the GPG plugin (just as your solution does). However, the fact that that command is not anywhere in the log leads me to believe that the `install` command is being called without that option.

Comment: It works now, so thank you. However, I still fail to see how the command-line flag wasn't doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Gaston's answer works well and worked first, so it'll stay accepted. However, I'm doing something slightly different.

Rather than disabling the plugin entirely, I've moved the plugin to a profile that only activates when `gpg.passphrase` is provided. I provide the passphrase locally, but Travis does not, so the GPG plugin is ignored in the build but exists when I need it.

[pom.xml](https://github.com/endreman0/java-json/blob/8920ac6c006b7cf458ef0d374947857bc3e26053/pom.xml#L42) and [build log](https://travis-ci.org/endreman0/java-json/builds/71344896).